# Different arrow line styes and different row sizes in tikzpicture

Tags: matrices, tikz-styles

I am using `tikzpicture` environment, together with `\matrix` command to draw a diagram. I have two questions:

1. Can I use different arrow line styles in the same matrix? For
   instance, the matrix called m, let's say, I want dashed arrow from
   `m-1-2` to `m-1-4` and solid arrow from `m-3-1` to `m-3-3`, also I want a
   solid arrow from `m-3-1` to `m-1-2`.
2. Can I use different row sizes in one matrix?

Comment: Hi mara, [Welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I removed the thanks and added some gloss to the question (click on edit to see what I did). Thanks is best expressed in the up voting of answers that help you. In addition, please provide us with a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that we can copy, paste, and play with your existing code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, and yes!

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzpicture
  [mymatrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=2cm,
    row 3/.style={minimum height=3cm}}
  ]
  \matrix[mymatrix] (m) {
    foo & bar & baz \\
    baz & foo & bar \\
    bar & baz & foo \\
  };
  \draw[dashed,->] (m-1-2) -- (m-1-3);
  \draw[->] (m-3-1) -- (m-3-3);
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Morbusg, I have read the answer and it is clear. I could understand that the height between the first and the second rows is the default one. Then, you defined the desired height between row 2 and 3 as minimum height=3cm. Am I right? As for the arrow styles, I need a dashed arrow instead of a dashed line from (m-1-2) -- (m-1-3). Please advice.

Comment: Plz do not trouble yourself to answer my previous question, I kept trying after I post my question, based on your answer, I found the solution, and I solved my current problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Mara: I'm sorry: I hadn't read properly the question. I added the arrow to the dashed line. If this answer helped solve the problem, please consider pressing the “Accept answer”-button `:-)`

Comment: @Mara: If you want to define a different row distance for a particular row, you could also use, for example, `\\[2cm]` at the end of the row (just like in LaTeX).